# Rails – Convert time duration to integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm needing to run a rails conditional against duration.

Durations are being formatted like the following (demonstrates a little over 14s):

```
duration = "00:00:14.01"
```

I'm wondering how I can convert the above duration to an integer, so I can write a conditional like the following:

```
if duration > 45
    raise "This video is longer than 45 seconds!"
end
```

Comment: It's not clear from your example, but is duration a string, or some class?  There aren't quote marks around the assignment, but that's not valid Ruby as it stands...

Comment: Sorry about that, it's a string – I've updated the original post to include quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the seconds as below :

```
require 'time'

t = Time.parse("00:00:14.01")
sec = t.hour*3600 + t.min*60 + t.sec
sec # => 14
```

Important method sets here are - [`Time#hour`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-hour), [`Time#min`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-min), [`Time#sec`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-sec).

As *@ChrisHeald* suggested -

```
 t = Time.parse("00:00:14.01") - Time.parse("00:00:00")
```

Comment: At first I liked the simplicity of your idea. But it's wrong...  You should multiple t.hour with 3600 etc to make it right, as you can't add apples to oranges...

Comment: @DannyVanHoof Thanks for pointing.. I don't know how Could I do such a mistake.. :)

Comment: You could go simpler: `t = Time.parse("00:00:14.01") - Time.parse("0:0")`

Comment: This falls apart if more than 24 hours. Hence Bartosz [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20818752/1477165) is a better option.

Answer (score 3):

Is `duration` a string?

If so, you can go with:

```
seconds = duration.split(':').reverse.map.with_index.sum do |m, i| 
  m.to_f * 60 ** i
end
```

:))

Answer (score 0):

Doing something like

```
duration.scan(/\d\d/).map(&:to_i).inject{|s, r| r + s * 60} / 60
```

will give you the time in seconds

Answer (score 0):

If you start with the string version of the duration stored in a variable called `duration`, then:

```
duration =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d.*)/
hours = $1.to_i
minutes = $2.to_i
seconds = $1.to_f.round
```

Then do the time math to convert it to a common unit for display, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write some type of conversion to a float, so you can compare it to an integer or float.

This is what happens when I get bored...  and love Ruby too much.

```
def duration_to_float(string)
  items = string.split(':').reverse
  ret = items.shift.to_f
  items.each_with_index do |item, index|
    ret += item.to_i * 60 ** (index + 1)
  end
  ret
end

puts duration_to_float('00:00:14.06')
puts duration_to_float('00:01:14.06')
puts duration_to_float('01:00:14.06')
```

This outputs:

```
14.06
74.06
3614.06
```

As an added advantage, you can pass in just minutes or just seconds, but it has to be a string.  E.g., "14.06" or "00:14.06" are the same as the first example.

Comment: Use `items.each.with_index(1)` and you can you can just do `60 ** index` in the block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strptime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime).

```
require 'time'
seconds = Time.strptime(duration, "%H:%M:%S") - Time.strptime("00:00:00", "%H:%M:%S") #=> 21
seconds.to_i
```

You get the time relative to the beginning of the day so I subtract that off to get the duration in seconds.